# How can i edit and delete a page in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

When i try to edit and delete an employee,an error will shows.

For delete

```
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CreateEmployeeController::deleteemployee()
```

For edit

```
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CreateEmployeeController::editemployee()
```

**Methods:**

```
public function editemployee($id)
{
   $employee = CreateEmployee::where('id',$id)->get();

   return view('app.admin.employee.editemployee',compact('employee'));
}

public function updateemployee(Request $request)
{

  CreateEmployee::where('id',$request->id)->update(array('username'=>$request->username,'area'=>$request->area_name));

  Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'channel details updated successfully'));

  return Redirect::action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@addemployee',array('id' => $request->id));

}


public function deleteemployee($id)
{

    $employee =  CreateEmployee::where('id',$id)->get();

    return view('app.admin.employee.deleteemployee',compact('employee'));
}


public function deleteconfirms($id)
{

     $employee = CreateEmployee::where('id',$id)->delete();

     Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'employee deleted successfully'));

     return Redirect::action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@addemployee');

}
```

Comment: can you post your route file for these routes?

Comment: Post route and form view please

Comment: Route::get('edit-employee','CreateEmployeeController@editemployee');

    Route::post('update-employee','CreateEmployeeController@)updateemployee');
    
    Route::get('delete-employee','CreateEmployeeController@deleteemployee');

    Route::post('delete-confirms','CreateEmployeeController@deleteconfirms');

Answer (score 1):

As I can see that your methods `deleteemployee` , `deleteconfirms` and `editemployee` are expecting the id field. 
While in your route you are not using any "Route parameters" (for details see [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters) ).
So, change your routes to include Route Parameters as follows. where `id` represents `employee_id`

```
Route::get('edit-employee/{id}','CreateEmployeeController@editemp‌​loyee');
Route::post('update-employee','CreateEmployeeController@upd‌​ateemployee');
Route::get('delete-employee/{id}','CreateEmployeeController@delet‌​eemployee');
Route::post('delete-confirms/{id}','CreateEmployeeController@dele‌​teconfirms');
```